# soup find link with specific `th` element appearing in DOM before

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to find specific links in my HTML. I have this code

```
website_link = infobox.find('a', class_='external', href=True)
```

This finds multiple links. But I only want links that are in a `td` element, that has a `th` Element before, with the content `Website`.

like this:

```
<tr>
  <th>
    Website
  </th>
  <td>
    <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="example_url">my_url</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Is it somehow possible to do limit it to these links?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using css selectors; try something like

```
infobox.select_one("th:-soup-contains(Website)+td a[href]").text
```

With your sample, the output should be

```
'my_url'
```